# str:tokenize Fails on the Less Than Character

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I'm parsing a text file using XSLT 1.0. I'm tokenizing on line breaks. Whenever I run into a '<' character the template stops and doesn't output anymore data.

The text file:

```
test1
test2 < test
test3
```

The template

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <vce>
    <!-- tokenize on line endings -->
    <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(.,'&#10;')">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="new-document" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </vce>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="new-document">
  <document>
    <content name="test">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </content>
  </document>
</xsl:template>
```

The output:

```
<vce>
  <document>
    <content name="test">test1</content>
  </document>
  <document>
    <content name="test">test2 </content>
  </document>
</vce>
```

Expected output:

```
<vce>
  <document>
    <content name="test">test1</content>
  </document>
  <document>
    <content name="test">test2 < test</content>
  </document>
  <document>
    <content name="test">test3</content>
  </document>
</vce>
```

Does str:tokenize have problems with certain characters?

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete details to allow us to reproduce the problem so tell us which XSLT processor you use, how you pass a text file to the XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: It's bundled into an application but I believe it's saxon parser.

Comment: Your "expected output" is invalid XML: the `<` character is not allowed except 1) when marking the start of a tag, 2) when escaped as `&lt;`, or 3) when contained in a `<![CDATA[...]]>` section.

Comment: Saxon is an XSLT processor, not an XML parser. It exists in several versions and editions but I am not sure it ever supported `str:tokenize` from EXSLT. Xalan Java does, as does libxslt, but your example "parsing a text file" is difficult to understand with XSLT 1.0 processors as they take XML input.

Comment: @spyderman4g63 **1.** See how to identify your processor here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033 **2.** Try to provide us with a reproducible example; the whole thing is a mystery now, because AFAIK there is no way to process a text file using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I believe the problem is with the data being passed to the xslt templates and not with the function itself.